# Could not execute the method ofthe activity

Tags: java, android, forceclose

I'm learning to use Eclipse and program Android apps. I'm currently using this book and I'm following along and I keep getting a huge error! The app will run in the emulator but the second I click the button ,the app force closes

I've started the book over 3 times in attempt to catch an error I missed but I'm starting to get discouraged and would appreciate help!

**This is the error i get on my log-----**

```
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     ... 11 more
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776): Caused by:     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class     {com.helloworld/com.helloworld.Hello}; have you declared this activity in your     AndroidManifest.xml?
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at     android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at     android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     at             com.helloworld.MainActivity.helloload(MainActivity.java:18)
05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776):     ... 14 more
```

**Here is my MainActivity.java code----**

```
package com.helloworld;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void helloload(View view) {
        Intent helloload = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hello.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(helloload);
    }
}
```

**Here is my activity_main.xml code-----**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="186dp"
    android:onClick="helloload"
    android:text="Hello"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my Hello.java code----**

```
package com.helloworld; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
public class Hello extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.hello);
    } 
}
```

**Here is my hello.xml code-----**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**HERE IS my HelloWorld Manifest-----**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.helloworld"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.helloworld.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Once I run the app and click the button the emulator states "It seems as if Hello World
has stopped working" It runs, but when I click the button it force closes and I get the 
errors stated in the log above.

Comment: You have to "register" your `Hello` Activity in `Manifest.xml`. Then it should works.

Comment: Did you read the logs...it says this:  `05-27 22:06:26.933: E/AndroidRuntime(1776): Caused by:     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class     {com.helloworld/com.helloworld.Hello}; have you declared this activity in your     AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 0):

You have registered just a Main Activity in Manifest file. Your logs clearly states that you have not entered info about your Hello Activity in your Manifest file.

Comment: Thank you! I know it was a newbie question- i guess i didn't read down far enough. Either way- thanks for the help :)

Comment: And, how would i declare this in the Manifest?

Comment: <activity
    android:name="com.helloworld.activity_name"
    android:label="@string/label_for_your_activity" >
</activity>

Comment: For the record your EXACTLY line of code for me to insert worked perfect :) of course i had to replace "activity_name" with my Hello activity ;p but thanks man! now i can finish progressing along with the book i bought :D

Comment: I think it would be better If you learn from tutorials instead of book.